# Add colors dynamically to LinearGradient

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm using using this data to fill a FlatList, each item contains a LinearGradient

```
const DATA = [
  {
    id: 'bd7acbea-c1b1-46c2-aed5-3ad53abb28ba',
    title: 'First Item',
    firstColor: "#f472a7",
    secondColor: "#d84351"
  },
  {
    id: '3ac68afc-c605-48d3-a4f8-fbd91aa97f63',
    title: 'Second Item',
    firstColor: "#50be71",
    secondColor: "#50be71"
  },
  {
    id: '58694a0f-3da1-471f-bd96-145571e29d72',
    title: 'Third Item',
    firstColor: "#e2bd4f",
    secondColor: "#e49074"
  }
];
```

I added two properties called "firstColor" and "secondColor", to fill the LinearGradient colors, but I'm having some issues doing that. I'm receiving this error:

```
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_ref3.secondColor')
```

Code:

```
    const Item = ({ title }, { firstColor }, { secondColor }) => (
        <LinearGradient
        colors={[{firstColor}, {secondColor} ]}
        style={styles.item}
        >
          <Text style={styles.title}>{title}</Text>
        </LinearGradient>
      );
      
      const renderItem = ({ item }) => (
        <Item title={item.title} />
      );
...

        <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
        <FlatList
          data={DATA}
          renderItem={renderItem}
          keyExtractor={item => item.id}
        />
      </SafeAreaView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
const Item = ({ title,  firstColor, secondColor}) => (
  <LinearGradient
    colors={[firstColor, secondColor ]}
    style={styles.item}
  >
    <Text style={styles.title}>{title}</Text>
  </LinearGradient>
);
      
const renderItem = ({ item}) => (
  <Item 
    firstColor={item.firstColor } 
    secondColor={ item.secondColor } 
    title={item.title} 
  />
);
```

Comment: Thanks! Now is working fine, just fix that part or the answer please: colors={[{firstColor}, {secondColor} ]} to colors={[ firstColor, secondColor ]}

Comment: Edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
 const LinearGradient = ({ color, firstColor, secondColor }) => {
const colorArr = [firstColor, secondColor];
return (
  <View>
    <Text>{color}</Text>
    <Text>{firstColor}</Text>
    <Text>{secondColor}</Text>
  </View>
);
```

};

can you try this, you were passing the data in the wrong way. I did some changes in similar example.